# load csv file to datagridview and ignore word with delimiter

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working with Csv file and datagridview in a C# project 
I try to load a CSV file with 2 delimiter '**,**' + '**;**' there is my problem! i need to ignore all word after comma except the last word example.csv:

> ```
> my1;;test1;good
> my2;cool;test,abcde;god
> my3;father;zyxw;
> my4;dad;word,fresh,example;banana
> ```

I want to display in my datagridview like this :

> ```
> my1;;test1;good
> my2;cool;abcde;god
> my3;father;zyxw;
> my4;dad;example;banana
> ```

As you can see, my goal is to add all line from CSV but if a **comma** appear get the last word.So far I using this code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader fileReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(csvPath, false);
                        string fileRow;
                        string[] fileDataField;

                        //Reading Data
                        while (fileReader.Peek() != -1)
                        {
                            fileRow = fileReader.ReadLine();
                            fileDataField = fileRow.Split(';');
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fileDataField);
                        }
                        fileReader.Dispose();
                        fileReader.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to solve this. Just add reference to `System.Linq` and set `fileDataField` as follows:

```
fileDataField = fileRow.Split(';')
               .Select(e=> e.LastIndexOf(",") >= 0 && e.IndexOf(",") < e.Length 
               ? e.Substring(e.LastIndexOf(",") + 1) 
               : e).ToArray();
```

Comment: Working perfectly, but i'm using a array for fixing this i have add .ToArray() thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually.. I realized that and just updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.StreamReader fileReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(csvPath, false);
string[] fileDataField;
string fileRow;

//Reading Data
while (fileReader.Peek() != -1) {
    fileRow = fileReader.ReadLine();
    fileDataField = fileRow.Split(';');

    //Declare temporary array to temporary store the values
    string[] tempItems = new string[fileDataField.Length];
    //Loop through the array and do comma check,
    //Cut the string if there's a comma in it
    //Else just add the normal value

    for (int i = 0; i < fileDataField.Length; i++) {
        tempItems[i] = fileDataField[i].Substring(fileDataField[i].LastIndexOf(",") + 1);
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(tempItems);
}
fileReader.Dispose();
fileReader.Close();
```

This should work. You could simply cut off the part of the string before and including the comma, and add the rest to the gridview. If no comma is found, the value is added without being altered.

**Edit:**
Should use an array instead of a list.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't understand when i'm testing this code and it's add : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] to my datagridview, do you know why?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The problem was adding a List to the GridView, now with an array it works